# Dictionary may contain a string or an array

Tags: python

I want to access the IDs in a dictionary, however the IDs are 90% a string and 10% an array.

This works with the string

```
IDs = MemberData.get('MemberDetails', {}).get('ID')
```

However the data can come through either way:

```
{ MemberData: {MemberDetails: [{'ID':55,'name':'John'},{'ID':56,'name':'Mike'}] }}
```

or

```
{ MemberData: {MemberDetails: {'ID':55,'name':'John'} }}
```

How can I return both instances as

```
IDs = [55,56]
IDs = [55]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for both cases:

```
def extract(d):
    data = d['MemberData']['MemberDetails']
    return [x['ID'] for x in data] if isinstance(data, list) else [data['ID']]
```

For example:

```
d1 = {'MemberData': {'MemberDetails': [{'ID':55, 'name':'John'}, {'ID':56, 'name':'Mike'}]}}
d2 = {'MemberData': {'MemberDetails': {'ID':55, 'name':'John'}}}

extract(d1)
=> [55, 56]
extract(d2)
=> [55]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that checks if the instance is a list and iterate over the element, otherwise assume a dictionary.

```py
def fetch_ids(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [z.get('ID') for z in x]
    else:
        return [x.get('ID')]

ids = fetch_ids(MemberData.get('MemberDetails', {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

`isinstance` is a good way to check what you've got and handle different behavior differently.

```
ids = MemberData.get('MemberDetails', {}).get('ID')

if isinstance(ids, dict):
  id_list = [ids['ID']]
elif isinstance(ids, list):
  id_list = [x['ID'] for x in ids]
else:
  # handle an error
  id_list = []
```